# Как сделать показ сразу всех строк таблицы в psql

Tags: psql

У меня есть база данных с таблицей. И когда я ввожу `SELECT * FROM <моя таблица>`.

То мне начинают показываться данные, вроде всё хорошо. Но в какой-то момент, на тысячной строке или что-то в этом роде.
Мне предлагают нажимать enter"далее", чтобы посмотроеть следущую строку. А у меня их сотни тысяч, мне не вариант постоянно нажимать enter. На скриншоте показал как это выглядит.

Есть у кого-то решения проблемы?
[image: psql]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\pset pager off
```

Русское сообщество stackoverflow имеет огромный фидбек, всем спасибо. Вот ответ на мой вопрос.